# How to add random class to div which is created dynamically in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I have created 18 div dynamically through jquery and after created div i have to add random class to some of the div

i have 12 div's and has class name like title and need to add 5 active classes among them

I tried by call function but it won't work

Following is my html

```
<body>
 <div class="container">

 </div>
</body>
```

Following is my custom js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 function createGridForGame(count, callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        $('.container').append("<div class='title"+i+"'>" + "</div>" );
     }
     callback();
}


createGridForGame(5, function() {
    var className = 'activeClass';  
    $("#container div").each(function(){
        var className = $(this).addClass((Math.random()*2));
        $(this).addClass(className);
    });
});


});
```

Comment: why are you using `callback`? You have used `$("#container div")`, but `container` is a class. what does this line mean `var className = $(this).addClass((Math.random()*2));`?

Comment: change from $("#container div")  to $(".container div")